# CakePHP index() vs view() and URL components

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am confused about the distinction and treatment of the `index()` and `view()` functions inside CakePHP 2.4.

Specifically, I am trying to modify a 3rd party API authored in CakePHP 2.4

Consider this Controller:

```
class EventsController extends AppController {
<snip>
  public function index() {
    if ($this->request->params['named']) {  
       $conditions = $this->request->params['named'];
    } else {
      $conditions = array();
   }
}
```

This allows me to construct a URL like `http://myserver/api/events/index/StartTime >=:12/EndTime <=15.json` and the StartTime and EndTime get passed into conditions when I do a find.

That's great.

Now that same Controller has this additional function:

```
public function view($id) {

}
```

This function seems to be called when I invoke a url like `http://myserver/api/events/1234.json`

I am trying to extend `view` with more parameters, just like index. For example, I'd like to invoke:

`http://myserver/api/events/1234/MonitorId =:3.json` and `MonitorId =:3` gets passed as a parameter to handle in view. I *don't* want to add these into the function definitions - it can be anything.

If I try and do this, I get a "Controller" not found, but this same approach works in index()

Can someone help me achieve my goal and help explain what is going on?

(IF it helps, the full code of the controller is [here](https://github.com/ZoneMinder/zoneminder/blob/master/web/api/app/Controller/EventsController.php))

Comment: You're just using ZoneMinder, you're not one of the authors, right?

Comment: I'm a contributor to ZM and for better or worse, maintain the API because no one else does -  and also developer of zmNinja

Comment: I see... was just wondering whether there's a preferred way to report possible security issues, but I just found https://github.com/ZoneMinder/zoneminder/issues/1801#issuecomment-2844067931, which I guess is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to explicitly call the `view` action to pass it more parameters.

So `api/events/view/218245/AlarmFrames >=: 80.json` works as intended and then I can get the parameters with `$conditions = $this->request->params['named'];`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are using CakePHP RESTful routing [routes.php](https://github.com/ZoneMinder/zoneminder/blob/master/web/api/app/Config/routes.php)

Here,

- `index` is used for listing all the resources e.g. all blog posts. URL `/events/index` is getting mapped to `index` method in controller automagically.
- `view` is used for showing a specific resource which can be identified by some unique identifier like `id` or `uuid` e.g. specific blog post. URL `/events/<some_identifier>` gets mapped to `view` method

What you need to do is modify `view` definition to read all query string parameters that you pass in URL and call `Model` accordingly. By default. `routes` parses the first string after `events` in URL to resource ID and passes it as first argument to `view` method in controller. This is scaffolded code.

You can use named parameters `$this->request->params['named']` in your `view` definition and construct your queries. No hard-coding.